# C : enQueue : How does create a new pointer to the tail?

Tags: c, queue, doubly-linked-list

Alright, So I have a `queue.h` that says:

```
typedef struct {
    int key;
    int value;
} data_t;

typedef struct queueNode {
    struct queueNode *next, *prev;
    data_t *data;
} QueueNode;
h
typedef struct queueType {
    QueueNode *head;
    QueueNode *tail;
} Queue;
```

And my goal now is to figure out how to iterate over the queue to find a specific Node, and later a specific Value, within said queue.

The issue I see is that I don't have a way to say `Queue{?}` to take me to a specific `queueNode`, and I don't know of a way to say:

```
for queueNode in queue{scan return `queueNode` if valid}.
```

I've recently crossed the threshold of figuring out how to use a global variable size to know exactly how many `queueNodes` there are, but that still leaves me with the same issues.

Comment: Can you tell how to get from the first one to the next one? Can you tell how to get from any one to the next one? Can you imagine that in a chain these techniques will allow you to look at all, one after the other? Then you need to just determine the right one. If you count with each step you have an index like into an array. If you look at the key you can search.

Comment: Thats the thing. From the head (the first queueNode) I can access the next queueNode with it's next value, and from there I can access the one after it with it's next value (so next->next->...->data) the thing is, these queues can have well over 20 nodes in them, and I don't know how to multiply the amount of "next->" statements in relation to the size to access the appropriate queueNode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With structures like this, a usual way to iterate over the list would be:

Using `next`

```
QueueNode *queue_find_forward(Queue *queue, int key)
{
    if(queue == NULL)
        return NULL;

    QueueNode *current = queue->head;

    while(current)
    {
        if(current->data->key == key)
            return current;

        current = current->next;
    }

    // no node has the requested key
    return NULL;
}
```

Using `prev`

```
QueueNode *queue_find_backwards(Queue *queue, int key)
{
    if(queue == NULL)
        return NULL;

    QueueNode *current = queue->tail;

    while(current)
    {
        if(current->data->key == key)
            return current;

        current = current->prev;
    }

    // no node has the requested key
    return NULL;
}
```

But be aware that the queue has to be properly initialized, the nodes have be to
properly initialized, the `next` pointer of the last element must point to
`NULL`, and the `prev` pointer of the first element must point to `NULL` as
well.

Both function do a check in the `while` loop:

```
        if(current->data->key == key)
```

I decided to use `key` for determining which element to look for. Of course you can
change that, you could check for the value or another property, or a
combination of both. This is up to you (or most likely the assignment you are
working on). The important thing is that you leave the loop once you've
found your element.

In `struct queueNode`, I'd change `data_t *data;` to `data_t data;`. I don't see
the benefit of having a pointer to `data_t`, you would need to allocate memory
for it, and would have to free it as well. It would increase the amount of code
you need to write for this. A pointer would only be useful if you are intending to have an array of
`data_t` objects per node, but otherwise not having it as pointer will make life
easier for you in the end.

Comment: Saddly the data_t *data; isn't my call. I cant' alter anything in the queue.h file, only the queue.c file.